# How should I go about improving the performance of this query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance

I have this Oracle query that is in certain environments occasionally using very slowly-performing Execution Plans.

What steps can I take in order to tune this query so that it consistently uses a faster Execution Plan? Or to rephrase, are there any specific areas that stand out as particularly inefficient or roundabout?

```
select 
 'RECEIVE-DONE' OP_TYPE,   
 sbmt.SUBMIT_NO, 
 wsr.USE_LUMP_PROC, 
 sf.* 
from ( 
 select 
 my.flow_id myflow_id, 
 done.flow_id flow_id, 
 done.status SFSTATUS, 
 from submit_flow my , submit_flow done 
  where my.submit_id=done.submit_id 
  and my.check_ord=done.check_ord 
  and my.emp_id = '1'
  and done.status
  in (1,2,3,4) 
  and ( (done.mainflow=1 and done.check_ord > 0) or (done.emp_id ='1' and done.type in (1,2,3) and done.type = my.type ) )  
  ) sf,  
  submit_list sbmt, wfserveroute wsr, emp emp 
where  
 sbmt.EMP_ID = emp.EMP_ID 
 and sf.SUBMIT_ID = sbmt.SUBMIT_ID 
 and ((sf.TYPE = 1 and sbmt.COMPLETED = 1 and sbmt.status = 2) or (sf.TYPE <> 1)) 
 and sbmt.FLOW_SCHEM  = wsr.SCHEM   
 and sbmt.SERVICENAME = wsr.FULLNAME 
 and wsr.CASE = 0 
 and not exists( 
 SELECT 1 FROM service_mst smst 
 WHERE   (smst.namespace||'.'||smst.name) = sbmt.SERVICENAME
 and  smst.not_view_at_inouttray = 1  
 )  order by sf.prc_date DESC
```

I found that instances of Table Access Full and Merge Join Cartesian within the Execution Plan are less than desirable in terms of speed, but I'm not sure of the tangible modifications to the SQL that would be required in order to encourage the usage of plans that would not include them.

The statistical data used for creating plans, for the tables in question, should be updated.

Comment: While not strictly related to your question, I would start by learning ANSI SQL join syntax, as the join syntax you are using has not been considered good practice for 30+ years. For questions about query performance, please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query plus the DDL for the tables including any indexes

Comment: On which columns did you create indexes?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit
All columns should have indexes.

Comment: Really **all** columns? Would be `submit_id, check_ord, emp_id, status, mainflow, check_ord, FLOW_SCHEM, SCHEM, SERVICENAME, FULLNAME, CASE, not_view_at_inouttray`

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of query,

- run it without the ORDER BY to evaluate the sorting cost
- look at the transformed SQL actually being executed and see how the IN clause are transformed, some are susceptible to be better rewritten as BETWEEN or even <= depending on the possible values of the column concerned (e.g. status)
- you have several OR in your WHERE clauses: evaluate the cardinality of each branches, you may find interest to replace by an UNION ALL
- you have string concatenation in your WHERE clause: could be a calculated column with index
- some of your WHERE clause could be helped by compound indexes
  ...

Comment: Will try to investigate further on these points.
Thanks a lot for the detailed advice.